# Dynamic Group By in a Query

Tags: sql

Is there a way to apply or not a group by into a query? for example, I have this:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
A    10   X
A    10   NULL
B    12   NULL 
B    12   NULL
```

I have to group by Col1 and Col2 only when I have a value in Col3, if Col3 is null, I don't need to group it. The result should be:

```
Col1 Col2
A    20  
B    12   
B    12
```

Maybe is not an elegant example, but this is the idea.
Thank you.

Comment: you need to group by Col1 and Col2 if AT LEAST 1 value in Col3 is not null?

Comment: It looks like your output does not match your requirements, why record  A is grouped, taking into consideration that Col3 is null

Comment: because there is at least one Col3 value that is not null

Comment: I think tr3 was tring to say the sane thing, but just use a filter in your where clause to remove null Col3 ( where Col3 is not null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a SQL Fiddle that does what you want:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7f07/2

Here's the SQL itself:

```
SELECT col1, sum(col2) as col2 FROM dataTable WHERE 
col1 in (SELECT col1 from dataTable WHERE col3 IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY col1
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2 FROM dataTable WHERE
(col1 not in 
 (SELECT col1 from dataTable WHERE col3 IS NOT NULL and col1 is not null))
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want all unique values of col1 when col3 is not null.  Otherwise, you want all values of col1.

Assuming you have a SQL engine that supports window functions, you can do this as:

```
select col1, sum(col2)
from (select t.*,
             count(col3) over (partition by col1) as NumCol3Values,
             row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col1) as seqnum
       from t
     ) t
group by col1,
         (case when NumCol3Values > 1 then NULL else seqnum end)
```

The logic is pretty much as you state it.  If there is any non-NULL value, then the second clause of the group by always evaluates to NULL -- everything goes in the same group.  If things are all NULL, then the clause evaluates to a sequence number, which puts each values on a separate row.

This is a bit more difficult without window functions.  If I assume that the minimum value of column 3 (when not NULL) is unique, then the following would work:

```
select t.col1,
       (case when minCol3 is null then tsum.col2 else t.col2 end) as col2
from t left outer join
     (select col1, sum(col2) as col2, 
             min(col3) as minCol3
      from t
     ) tsum
     on t.col1 = tsum.col1
where minCol3 is NULL or t.col3 = MinCol3
```

Comment: shouldn't you test for max(col3) instead of min()?

Comment: well, for the a,10 set, isn't null the min(col3)?  And the max(col3) would be X?

Comment: @Beth . . . NULL is ignored in almost all aggregation functions, such as `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM`, and so on.  In some databases (such as Oracle), it is possible that NULL strings are converted to empty strings but that is a special, non-ANSI case.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I wasn't 100% sure.  When I sort by values in a column, the nulls always sort as the first values.

Answer (score 0):

re: *Is there a way to apply or not a group by into a query?*
Not directly, but you can break it down by groupings and then UNION the results together.

Does this work?

```
Select col1, sum(col2)
from table
group by col1, col2
having max(col3) is not null

union all

select col1, col2
from table t left outer join
 (Select col1, col2
 from table
 group by col1, col2
 having max(col3) is not null) g
where g.col1 is null
```